# Buttons with zero width still affect parent's width in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm trying to change the width of some `button`s based on hover state. That is, they should have width 0 initially and automatic width on hover.

```css
.parent {
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid darkblue;
}

.child {
  float: left;
  width: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="child">a</button>
  <button class="child">b</button>
  <button class="child">c</button>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4rsd84yg/9/)

This works as expected on most browsers (screenshot from Firefox):

[image: Non-hovered in Firefox]

However, Safari seems to still consider the (zero-width, invisible) buttons width for calculation of the parent's width:

[image: Non-hovered in Safari]

Is there a reason for Safari's unusual rendering I'm missing or might it just be a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this seems to be a bug. Safari's Web Inspector says that the width of each button is indeed zero, so clearly it's not the buttons that are the problem. Perhaps Safari is calculating the width of the containing block based on the content in each button disregarding the width declarations, or something.

Setting `max-width` instead of `width` seems to work, which just makes this all the more bizarre:

```css
.parent {
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid darkblue;
}

.child {
  float: left;
  max-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  max-width: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="child">a</button>
  <button class="child">b</button>
  <button class="child">c</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Fair enough, I filed a [bug report here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=171430) (couldn't find an existing one for this).